# Can Agda proofs be trusted and do they conform to a specific, well-defined type theory?

Tags: agda

When using Agda proofs, how can you know whether to trust it? Also, do they conform to a specific, well-defined type theory?

---

###### [Credit](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants/126290#126290)

Comment: Jesper Cockx is working on this: https://jesper.sikanda.be/posts/veni-announcement.html

Comment: I think this question is actually a valid one, or at the very least very close to one. Agda has many features, many of which don't play well together and some of which are even unsound on their own. The fact that the specification of core Agda is the subject of current research makes the question "which part(s) of Agda have fully worked out, consistent theories" a good one. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Is there something particular about Agda, or can we expect the same sort of question for every other proof assistant? If the latter, it would make sense to have a wiki question "What is known about the trustworthiness of major proof assistants?" or some such.

Comment: This question was an example question on the Area 51 proposal for this site.  It was originally asked by Martín Hötzel Escardó

Comment: Are we supposed to "import" those questions? And why isn't Martín Escardó asking this?

Comment: @AndrejBauer The questions are just titles.  If someone understands the point of the question they could ask it or something similar and write a good full question text and pick the answer they think best answers the question as written.  (It would be good to mention where is came from.)

Comment: So I can edit the question and turn it from a stub to a real one?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I would be glad if you did; I was thinking of doing so myself but your edit would probably be better

Comment: Similar, and more general question, on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33065965/3648282

Comment: We have a question about "proof assistants" in general: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/340/393. I think Agda deserves a special place because it clearly has a different attitude to soundness.

Comment: (And https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1162/393 seems related on the "continuum of trustworthiness").